Python pandas replacing new values
I am having such pandas values as follows:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat':('-10.1','-10.2','-10.3','-10.4','-10.5','-10.6'),
    'Lon':('90.000','90.050','90.100','90.150','90.200','90.250'),
    'Position':('-9999.999','-9999.999','-9999.999','-9999.999','-9999.999','-9999.999')})
df1 = df1.set_index(['Lat','Lon'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat':('-10.2','-10.5'),
    'Lon':('90.050','90.200'),
    'Position':('50','100')
})
df2 = df2.set_index(['Lat','Lon'])

output=df1.combine_first(df2).reset_index()

and the answers as follows:
     Lat     Lon   Position
0  -10.1  90.000  -9999.999
1  -10.2  90.050  -9999.999
2  -10.3  90.100  -9999.999
3  -10.4  90.150  -9999.999
4  -10.5  90.200  -9999.999
5  -10.6  90.250  -9999.999

However, I am expecting the output as follows:
     Lat     Lon   Position
0  -10.1  90.000  -9999.999
1  -10.2  90.050  50.0
2  -10.3  90.100  -9999.999
3  -10.4  90.150  -9999.999
4  -10.5  90.200  100.0
5  -10.6  90.250  -9999.999

anynone got an ideas, please help. Thanks in advance.

df2.combine_first(df1).reset_index() swap df2 and df1 order

@PandaKim thanks alot..your answer is helping me and appreciate that

We can try the following:
df1.loc[df2.index,:] = df2

Output:
               Position
Lat   Lon              
-10.1 90.000  -9999.999
-10.2 90.050         50
-10.3 90.100  -9999.999
-10.4 90.150  -9999.999
-10.5 90.200        100
-10.6 90.250  -9999.999


thanks alot. your answer is helping me and appreciate that. It looks simple.

import pandas as pd

# Define the dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat': ('-10.1', '-10.2', '-10.3', '-10.4', '-10.5', '-10.6'),
    'Lon': ('90.000', '90.050', '90.100', '90.150', '90.200', '90.250'),
    'Position': ('-9999.999', '-9999.999', '-9999.999', '-9999.999', '-9999.999', '-9999.999')
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat': ('-10.2', '-10.5'),
    'Lon': ('90.050', '90.200'),
    'Position': ('50', '100')
})


You can merge both dfs
result = df1.merge(df2, on=['Lat', 'Lon'], how='left', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))




Then combine the columns created
result['Position'] = result['Position_df2'].combine_first(result['Position_df1'])




The finally drop the temporary column
result = result.drop(columns=['Position_df1', 'Position_df2'])



##########################
result = df1.merge(df2, on=['Lat', 'Lon'], how='left', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
result['Position'] = result['Position_df2'].combine_first(result['Position_df1'])
result = result.drop(columns=['Position_df1', 'Position_df2'])


Thanks for the great efforts by you. I will try using this suggestion for my work..

A fine answer, but this applies to answers as well as questions: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
